# Как DataSet вывести через цикл for()?

Tags: c#, foreach

В цикле foreach() нормально выводит содержимое ячеек. А цикле for() вместо содержимого выводит ColumnName. Как вывести в этом цикле содержимое?

```
        DataSet dataSet;
        string filePath = @"D:\file.xls";

        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)))
            {
                dataSet = reader.AsDataSet();
            }
```

В этом цикле нормально выводит содержимое ячейки.

```
                foreach (DataTable thisTable in dataSet.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in thisTable.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in thisTable.Columns)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

А в этом цикле ColumnName. Как вывести содержимое?

```
                for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataSet.Tables["Data"].Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < dataSet.Tables["Data"].Columns.Count; n++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(dataSet.Tables["Data"].Columns[n]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `"Data"` -> `i`,  `Console.Write(dataSet.Tables[i].Rows[j][n]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так, может быть ты там где то запутался...

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    DataTable thisTable = dataSet.Tables[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < thisTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        DataRow row = thisTable.Rows[j];

        for (int n = 0; n < thisTable.Columns.Count; n++)
        {
            DataColumn column = thisTable.Columns[n];

            Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
        }
    }
}
```